# Handling different heights with inline-block DIVs

Tags: html, css

I have some `<div>`s inside a styled blockquote. I have set the max-width and inline-block in the `<div>`s so it could place multiple `div`s on the same y-position when the screen has enough width.

I have also set some paddings between the `div`s, so it still look very good even if they stick together.

But here is a problem, If there are multiple `div`s on the same y-position, when the next DIV has to be "on the next line", the y-position will be under the DIV with the highest height.

**Current:**
[image: Current]

**Expected:**
[image: Expected]

The pictures are captured in jsfiddle, so here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/gp6ua49y/

---

**HTML Code:**

```
<blockquote>
    <div style="margin: 10px; vertical-align: top; max-width: 47%; display: inline-block;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.<cite>Mr. A</cite></div>
    <div style="margin: 10px; vertical-align: top; max-width: 47%; display: inline-block;">Lorem ipsum<cite>Miss B</cite></div>
    <div style="margin: 10px; vertical-align: top; max-width: 47%; display: inline-block;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam feugiat, ipsum sit amet tempus maximus, dolor libero volutpat mi, eu vestibulum felis eros id nisl.<cite>Mr. C</cite></div>
    <div style="margin: 10px; vertical-align: top; max-width: 47%; display: inline-block;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam feugiat, ipsum sit amet tempus maximus, dolor libero volutpat mi, eu vestibulum felis eros id nisl. Nullam tincidunt elementum mi, nec rutrum velit vestibulum sit amet. Nunc viverra euismod efficitur. Suspendisse pharetra tincidunt fringilla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.<cite>Mr. D</cite></div>
</blockquote>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
blockquote  {
    font-family: Georgia, 'whmChinese', serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-style: italic;
    margin: 0.25em 0;
    padding: 0.35em 40px;
    line-height: 1.45;
    position: relative;
    color: #383838;
}

.blockquote {
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-style: italic;
}

blockquote:before {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 10px;
    content: "\201C";
    font-size: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -20px;
    top: -20px;
    color: #7a7a7a;
}

cite {
    color: #999999;
    font-size: 14px;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

cite:before {
    content: "\2014 \2009";
}
```

Comment: don't think there is a pure CSS solution to this, you will have to consider using some js/jquery

Answer (score 0):

If the data are all static, css can do it easily. 
Kindly check this source code:
https://jsfiddle.net/csdf8euk/8

I added few styles like below and remove some inline styles:

```
.holder{
  width: 700px;
}
.holder div{
  display: inline-block;
}
.a{
  padding: 10px; vertical-align: top; width: 200px;
}
.b{
  padding: 10px; vertical-align: top; width: 150px;
}
.c{
  padding: 10px; vertical-align: top; width: 250px;
}
.d{
  padding: 10px; margin-top: -100px; vertical-align: top; width: 340px;
}
```

If that is what you plan to do, you can adjust the sizes of width.

Comment: The width of the blockquotes are based on the length and I want it to fit the browser's width (i.e. if the width of the div cannot fit in the same line, go to the next line but keep the y-position as top as possible). So ... hard-coding is not my solution needed.

Comment: I understand, maybe you may need consider jquery plugins. Check the links:
http://www.bootply.com/aUIYcAQi2m , 
http://jsfiddle.net/schmidjon/6Z3sn/